# CorrecT formula to change #N/A value to "Not SKU found"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

TABLE REFERENCE WHERE YOU CAN CHECK IF THE LINK OF THE SKU IS AVAILABLE

SHEET NAME: 1688 Links

| COLUMN A | COLUMN B |
| --- | --- |
| 123-HSFB-1 | https://detail.1688.com/offer/629615749375.html |
| 123-HSFB-2 |  |

TABLE WHERE YOU NEED TO RETURN THE VALUE FROM THE TABLE ABOVE

SHEET NAME: Sheet 1

| COLUMN A | COLUMN B |
| --- | --- |
| 123-HSFB-1 | (VALUE WILL RETURN THE LINK IF IT'S AVAILABLE) |
| 123-HSFB-2 | (VALUE TO RETURN WILL BE "NO LINK FOUND" IF THE VALUE ON THE TABLE ABOVE IS EMPTY) |
| 123-HSFB | (VALUE TO RETURN WILL BE "NO SKU FOUND" SINCE COLUMN A IS NOT FOUN ON THE TABLE) |

The formula I created in Google Sheet for this would be:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'1688 Links'!$A:$B,2,0)=ISBLANK(B2),"Link not found",IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'1688 Links'!$A:$B,2,0)=ISNA(B2),"Not listed",INDEX('1688 Links'!$B:$B,MATCH(A2,'1688 Links'!$A:$A,0))))
```

I can get the result for both 123-HSFB-1 and 123-HSFB-2 however 123-HSFB is always showing #N/A and I'm getting a error "Did not find value '123-HSFB' in VLOOKUP evaluation"

Need help on how can I get #N/A to show up as "SKU not found"

Comment: Would you mind changing your all-caps text to normal casing?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(LEN(A2)=0,"",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,'1688 Links'!$A:$B,2,0)), "SKU not found", IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(A2,'1688 Links'!$A:$B,2,0)), "Link not found", VLOOKUP(A2,'1688 Links'!$A:$B,2,0))))
```

This is the formula you need. You can check this [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1awKYblL88Dir7ZdXdfktqcAmWzB13viqBgw9TAyzs7Y/edit?usp=sharing). I just added an extra check for LEN(A2)=0. This way you can paste the formula in all the cells in column B and you'll get a value when column A has an entry on the same line.

If you don't need such a check, you can use the following

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,'1688 Links'!$A:$B,2,0)), "SKU not found", IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(A2,'1688 Links'!$A:$B,2,0)), "Link not found", VLOOKUP(A2,'1688 Links'!$A:$B,2,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`XLOOKUP` (which is basically VLOOKUP 2.0) has error handling built in. Pairing that with `BYROW` let’s you enter this single formula in one cell and it will automatically expand/contract without any manual formula dragging. Try:

```
=BYROW($D$4:$D,
 LAMBDA(r,
   IF(r="","",
     IF(XLOOKUP(r,A:A,B:B,"SKU NOT FOUND",0,1)="",
       "NO LINK FOUND",
     XLOOKUP(r,A:A,B:B,"SKU NOT FOUND",0,1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: @J.A were you able to try the above solution?